# Norm and evaluation hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, hilbert-spaces

Good evening.
Note: $||x||=|f|^{2}+|g|^{2}=1$

I have a question about notation mainly and about evaluation of something.
In one paper we have a matrix $$M = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2& \\
1 & 1&\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
$$N=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \\
3 & 0 &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In the article I am reading, it is said that $w(M^{*}N)=3$, where $w=\sup\{|\langle Tx,x\rangle||x\in H,||x||=1\}$
Also, $$|| |N|^{2}+|M|^{2} ||=15.3007$$
My first question is, how does one find that $w(M^{*}N)=3$, also i am confused as to what does $|N|$ mean? Please write a definition and step by step evaluation of both cases if possible. Here is my try
$$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & \\
2 & 1 &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
\times \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & \\
3 & 0 &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & \\
5 & 2 & \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now when we look for $M^{*}Nx$ we get
$$=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 0 & \\
5 & 2 & \\
\end{pmatrix}
\times
\begin{pmatrix}
f &  \\
g &  \\
\end{pmatrix}
=(3f,5f+2g)
$$
Which when we take dot product of with $x=(f,g)$ we get
$\langle (3f,5f+2g),(f,g)\rangle = 3f^{2}+5fg+2g^{2}$
Now taking absolute value, we get
$$|\langle M^{*}Nx,x\rangle|\leq 3|f^{2}|+5|fg|+2|g^{2}|\leq 3|f^{2}|+2|g^{2}|+5\frac{|f|^{2}+|g|^{2}}{2}=5+3|f^{2}|+2|g^{2}|.$$
I do not know how to proceed here to obtain 3 as the upper bound for the numerical radius.
Also, I have no idea what $|N|$ is for a matrix. Also what $||N||$ is, I have no clue.
Thank you for answering and reading this!

Comment: If $f=g=2^{-1/2}$ you get $3/2+5/2+2/2=5.$ Still it is not the maximal value, but certainly greater than $3.$

Comment: It is indeed weird how they obtained it in the paper...Maybe the reviewers didnt do a good job...Do you maybe have any idea what does $|N|$ of a matrix mean, also what is a matrix norm, that is $||N||$?

Comment: Sometimes $|N|$ means $(N^TN)^{1/2}$.